# is it possible to use header location to the same page in php?

Tags: php, redirect

This is my first question! I wrote an index.php and then I wrote another file, backend.php. I included this file in index.php.

In the file backend.php I have a class with many methods that manage many actions about payments and checks. The important part that I can't manage to solve is a method where I check values, and base on these values I chose if to capture the payment or call another method that redirects to the same page, in this case index.php but with URL parameters.

It doesn't redirect at all. This is the code of the method that (successfully) checks the values:

```
if (in_array($result, $CWA)) $this->capturePayment();

if (in_array($result, $DNCWA)) $this->redirectManager("unknown");

if (in_array($result, $DNCWARCHTR)) $this->redirectManager("retry");
```

And this is the method that it doesn't redirect. Honestly I created this second method thinking that could make a difference, I was happy to call the redirect in the first method, but it doesn't work, the index goes on like if there was no call to redirect:

```
public function redirectManager($reason)
{
    $retry = "An error occurred during the transaction. Please try again.";
    $unknownError = "An unknown error occurred during the transaction. Please consult your credit card issuer.";
    $success = "Transaction successfully completed. Thank you.";

    if ($reason == "unknown") {
        header("Location: index.php?result=failed&response=" . $unknownError);
    } elseif ($reason == "retry") {
        header("Location: index.php?result=failed&response=" . $retry);
    } else {
        header("Location: index.php?result=success&response=" . $success);
    }
}
```

I read other posts about this issue on stackoverflow, they all talk about adding ob_start() at the top, I added it as mentioned in these posts, but it didn't help at all. Why I can't redirect? I created complicated methods but I'm stuck with this small thing.

Thank you very much for your patience and help.

Elliot

Comment: ob_start() prevent the "Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by..." if you put it at very begin. Maybe you have the warning and is masked by configuration. Most php configuration do not show warning as first in redirectManager() put the following commands ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(-1); the first tell php to print errors, the second specify to print all error type (including warning)

Comment: Do you have any output (HTML, messages, blank space/line break before the opening PHP tag etc) before this? If yes, then you need to move it since headers can only be called before any out output. You should also always add an `exit;` after a `header('location: ...')` to prevent it from continuing page execution. And to be 100% sure that the if-statements work as expected, you can replace your header-calls to just `die('foobar')` and see if you see that, You can use different messages for different redirects to see that it's the correct one being triggered.

Comment: @RobertoBraga , nothing solved, no error or warnings, I see the redirect in the console but it never happened, It's very strange, I think I will need to find another solution. I also followed Eriksson suggestions, the issue is exactly like it was before. I have no idea why on this specific code is not working, on other tests that I wrote I could redirect with no issues.